# Ansible generate an ec2 tag Name with an incremental number

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm trying to launch a N number of ec2 instances using ansible with the tag:Name like "nginx1, nginx2" depending on the N number of instances, I'm pretty sure there is a way but I don't know how

```
 - name: Nginx Nodes
   ec2:
    key_name: "{{ key_name }}"
    region: "{{ region }}"
    instance_type: t2.nano
    image: "{{ nginx_ami }}"
    group: nginxsg
    exact_count: 2
    count_tag: 
      Name: "{{ nginx_name }}"
    instance_tags:
       Name: "{{ nginx_name }}"
       Environment: "{{ env }}"
    monitoring: no
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ AWS.db_subnets | random }}"
    assign_public_ip: yes
  register: nignx_instance
```

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this, adjust this example as per your requirement.

```
- name: Nginx Nodes
   ec2:
    key_name: "{{ key_name }}"
    region: "{{ region }}"
    instance_type: t2.nano
    image: "{{ nginx_ami }}"
    group: nginxsg
    instance_tags:
       Name: "{{ nginx_name }}-{{ item.0 + 1 }}"
       Environment: "{{ env }}"
    monitoring: no
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ item.1 }}"
    assign_public_ip: yes
  with_indexed_items: "{{ AWS.db_subnets }}"
  register: nignx_instance
```

For complete reference, consult this [link](https://github.com/arbabnazar/ansible-aws-roles/blob/master/roles/ec2instance/tasks/main.yml)

Comment: Forgot to remove `exact_count`.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Thanks

Comment: @ArbabNazar The problem with this approach is that I'm depending on the amount subnets I have, what happens if I want more machines than the numbers of subnets? maybe creating an array with the same size of the amount of ec2 I need first and then use with_indexed_items.